# Sage problem - numeric solving trigonometric equation

Tags: sagemath

I am relatively new to Sage. Can someone please help me how to solve:

$$ \tan (x) - x/10 = 0$$ numerically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Sage docs](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/numerical/sage/numerical/optimize.html):

```
find_root(tan(x)-x/10, a, b)
```

find a numerical root of this function on the interval $[a,b]$. The numerical method is likely to have problems with discontinuities of $\tan x$, so it is best to pick intervals between $\pi/2+\pi n$. For example,

```
find_root(tan(x)-x/10, pi/2, pi/2+pi)
```

returns `3.47614030869725`,

```
find_root(tan(x)-x/10, pi/2+pi, pi/2+2*pi)
```

returns `6.886235172066371`, and so on. You can write a `for` loop to produce a bunch of those.

Comment: Thank you, but this would not be the right answer. In this point there is intersection with asymptote of tan. Please see the picture http://pokit.org/get/img/cd9b7c5202f47e988b4ae5da05ca1984.jpg . The first correct answer would be 3.47614030869725 .

Comment: That's right; I corrected the answer.